# Database is seen in 'show db' even after dropping the database successfully

Tags: mongodb

We have following configuration of mongodb:(journal enabled)
On machines-1 have following servers 
       mongod - 5
       config server - 2
       mongos -  1 
On machines-2 have following servers
       mongod - 5
       config server - 1

We ran dropDatabase command from mongos successfully.
We saw the dropped database in the output of show dbs command(ran from mongos)
even after dropping the database successfully.

We observed show dbs command (ran from each mongod) are following:
1. Dropped database was not seen only mongod1 and mongod4.

Why dropped database are seen in output of show dbs command, even after dropping the database successfully ?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Find Logs of 00150812 database below:

MONGOS LOGS:

```
Line 17937: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] DBConfig unserialize: 00150812 { _id: "00150812", partitioned: true, primary: "shard0000" }
Line 17937: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] DBConfig unserialize: 00150812 { _id: "00150812", partitioned: true, primary: "shard0000" }
Line 17938: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] created new distributed lock for 00150812.Database on 192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000 ( lock timeout : 900000, ping interval : 30000, process : 0 )
Line 17939: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] ChunkManager: time to load chunks for 00150812.Database: 0ms sequenceNumber: 75 version: 28|1
Line 17940: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] DROP DATABASE: 00150812
Line 17941: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] DBConfig::dropDatabase: 00150812
Line 17942: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] about to log metadata event: { _id: "CSS-FU-1-2013-09-23T19:47:28-331", server: "CSS-FU-1", clientAddr: "N/A", time: new Date(1379965648710), what: "dropDatabase.start", ns: "00150812", details: {} }
Line 17943: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154]      removed entry from config server for: 00150812
Line 17944: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154]      dropping sharded collection: 00150812.Database
Line 17945: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] about to log metadata event: { _id: "CSS-FU-1-2013-09-23T19:47:28-332", server: "CSS-FU-1", clientAddr: "N/A", time: new Date(1379965648862), what: "dropCollection.start", ns: "00150812.Database", details: {} }
Line 17946: Mon Sep 23 22:47:28 [conn17154] about to acquire distributed lock '00150812.Database/CSS-FU-1:35000:1379577748:1804289383:
Line 17953: { "_id" : "00150812.Database",
Line 17956: Mon Sep 23 22:47:29 [conn17154] distributed lock '00150812.Database/CSS-FU-1:35000:1379577748:1804289383' acquired, ts : 52409ad0ed8f24e472bdd5d0
Line 17957: Mon Sep 23 22:47:29 [conn17154] ChunkManager::drop : 00150812.Database
Line 17958: Mon Sep 23 22:47:29 [conn17154] ChunkManager::drop : 00150812.Database   all locked
Line 17991: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154] ChunkManager::drop : 00150812.Database   removed shard data
Line 17992: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154] ChunkManager::drop : 00150812.Database   removed chunk data
Line 17993: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0000 192.168.11.20:10000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" } 0x235cad0
Line 17993: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0000 192.168.11.20:10000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" } 0x235cad0
Line 17994: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0001 192.168.11.20:15000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0001", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:15000" } 0x7fc388097290
Line 17994: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0001 192.168.11.20:15000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0001", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:15000" } 0x7fc388097290
Line 17995: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0002 192.168.11.20:20000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0002", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:20000" } 0x7fc388073c70
Line 17995: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0002 192.168.11.20:20000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0002", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:20000" } 0x7fc388073c70
Line 17996: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0003 192.168.11.20:25000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0003", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:25000" } 0x7fc3880709f0
Line 17996: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0003 192.168.11.20:25000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0003", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:25000" } 0x7fc3880709f0
Line 17997: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0004 192.168.11.20:30000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0004", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:30000" } 0x7fc3940313c0
Line 17997: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0004 192.168.11.20:30000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0004", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:30000" } 0x7fc3940313c0
Line 17998: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0005 192.168.11.21:40000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0005", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:40000" } 0x7fc388071760
Line 17998: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0005 192.168.11.21:40000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0005", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:40000" } 0x7fc388071760
Line 17999: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0006 192.168.11.21:45000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0006", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:45000" } 0x7fc3a40396c0
Line 17999: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0006 192.168.11.21:45000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0006", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:45000" } 0x7fc3a40396c0
Line 18000: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0007 192.168.11.21:50000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0007", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:50000" } 0x7fc39c0781a0
Line 18000: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0007 192.168.11.21:50000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0007", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:50000" } 0x7fc39c0781a0
Line 18001: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0008 192.168.11.21:55000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0008", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:55000" } 0x7fc3a81f0ff0
Line 18001: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0008 192.168.11.21:55000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0008", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:55000" } 0x7fc3a81f0ff0
Line 18002: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0009 192.168.11.21:60000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0009", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:60000" } 0x7fc3940300e0
Line 18002: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]     setShardVersion  shard0009 192.168.11.21:60000  00150812.Database  { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0009", shardHost: "192.168.11.21:60000" } 0x7fc3940300e0
Line 18007: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154] ChunkManager::drop : 00150812.Database   DONE
Line 18008: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154] about to log metadata event: { _id: "CSS-FU-1-2013-09-23T19:50:50-333", server: "CSS-FU-1", clientAddr: "N/A", time: new Date(1379965850345), what: "dropCollection", ns: "00150812.Database", details: {} }
Line 18013: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154] distributed lock '00150812.Database/CSS-FU-1:35000:1379577748:1804289383' unlocked. 
Line 18015: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]    DBConfig::dropDatabase: 00150812 dropped sharded collections: 1
Line 18016: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn17154]    DBConfig::dropDatabase: 00150812 dropped sharded collections: 0
Line 18051: Mon Sep 23 22:51:20 [conn17160] couldn't find database [00150812] in config db
Line 18053: Mon Sep 23 22:51:20 [conn17160]      put [00150812] on: shard0005:192.168.11.21:40000
Line 18054: Mon Sep 23 22:51:20 [conn17160] DROP DATABASE: 00150812
Line 18055: Mon Sep 23 22:51:20 [conn17160] DBConfig::dropDatabase: 00150812
Line 18056: Mon Sep 23 22:51:20 [conn17160] about to log metadata event: { _id: "CSS-FU-1-2013-09-23T19:51:20-334", server: "CSS-FU-1", clientAddr: "N/A", time: new Date(1379965880999), what: "dropDatabase.start", ns: "00150812", details: {} }
Line 18057: Mon Sep 23 22:51:21 [conn17160]      removed entry from config server for: 00150812
Line 18058: Mon Sep 23 22:51:21 [conn17160]    DBConfig::dropDatabase: 00150812 dropped sharded collections: 0
Line 18060: Mon Sep 23 22:51:36 [conn17160]      dropped primary db for: 00150812
Line 18061: Mon Sep 23 22:51:36 [conn17160] about to log metadata event: { _id: "CSS-FU-1-2013-09-23T19:51:36-335", server: "CSS-FU-1", clientAddr: "N/A", time: new Date(1379965896464), what: "dropDatabase", ns: "00150812", details: {} }
Line 18062: Mon Sep 23 22:51:36 [conn17160] couldn't find database [00150812] in config db
Line 18064: Mon Sep 23 22:51:36 [conn17160]      put [00150812] on: shard0005:192.168.11.21:40000
```

MONGOD1 LOGS:

```
Line 19629: Mon Sep 23 22:47:29 [conn2603] runQuery called 00150812.$cmd { drop: "Database" }
Line 19630: Mon Sep 23 22:47:29 [conn2603] run command 00150812.$cmd { drop: "Database" }
Line 19681: Mon Sep 23 22:50:43 [conn2603] dropCollection: 00150812.Database
Line 19682: Mon Sep 23 22:50:44 [conn2603] create collection 00150812.$freelist {}
Line 19684: Mon Sep 23 22:50:44 [conn2603] command 00150812.$cmd command: { drop: "Database" } ntoreturn:1 reslen:124 708ms
Line 19719: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn2603] runQuery called admin.$cmd { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" }
Line 19720: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn2603] run command admin.$cmd { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" }
Line 19721: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn2603] command: { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" }
Line 19723: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn2603] command admin.$cmd command: { setShardVersion: "00150812.Database", configdb: "192.168.11.20:62000,192.168.11.20:65000,192.168.11.21:38000", version: Timestamp 0|0, serverID: ObjectId('523aaf94ed8f24e472bdd592'), authoritative: true, shard: "shard0000", shardHost: "192.168.11.20:10000" } ntoreturn:1 reslen:57 0ms
Line 19804: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn8756] runQuery called 00150812.$cmd { dropDatabase: 1 }
Line 19805: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn8756] run command 00150812.$cmd { dropDatabase: 1 }
Line 19806: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn8756] dropDatabase 00150812
Line 19807: Mon Sep 23 22:50:50 [conn8756] dropDatabase 00150812
Line 19837: Mon Sep 23 22:54:43 [conn8756] remove file /u01/shard1/00150812.ns
Line 19838: Mon Sep 23 22:54:43 [conn8756] command 00150812.$cmd command: { dropDatabase: 1 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:59 232912ms
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

T&R,
JRV

Comment: Is `https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3701` related to the one you are facing!